# MS Access recovery function

Tags: ms-access

I'm just wondering what approach can I do to achieve recovery of the whole system application? When the app was suddenly turned off or when the electricity was suddenly down how can I recover all the data?

Btw, Im using MS Access. I just want some ideas for this because I really dont know what to do. Thank you

Comment: How much data could you lose due to power out - one record? If data was never committed to table there is nothing to recover. Repeat the data entry/edit.

Comment: @June7 I dont know how much data but I know its a lot because the system is inventory. They are asking if I can add a recovery function for the system. I already manage to add a function where they can backup the database and then restore it but what they want is automatic recovery when the electricity is suddenly out and when its back the system can automatically recover all the pending or stopped processes before the system crashed.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do, is to make a copy of the database.

Then open Access, create a new database.

Go to *Files* and close this database.

Now, from *Database Tools*, click *Compact & Repair* and select the copy you initially made.

If success, fine; if fail, you'll probably have to use a third-party tool.

*Addendum*:

To protect fully against a power outage, only an **UPS** can do that.

Comment: Mark asked for: _achieve recovery of the whole system application_. A power-out may (not will) leave the database in an inconsistent state which C&R typically can handle. Unsaved data in a typical Access application is one record which will be lost. To protect against a power outage, only an UPS can do that.

Comment: Oh, you might be right, I misread the question a little. Sorry to bother you

Comment: Ah, no problem, @ErikvonAsmuth